# Loop Through Nested JSON Response PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to loop through and return data ('rank' from 'rank_details') from a returned JSON response.

Here is a snippet of the JSON response (what I'm getting from: $array = json_decode($apiResponse); )

```
(object) array(
   'obj' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'I\'m a HellRazor (feat. Crucifix)',
       'id' => 13859011,
       'data' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2019-10-27T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 1.9610844011276853,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 191,
               'country' => 'RU',
               'score' => 1.9610844011276853,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2019-12-04T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 14.70808550760029,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 9,
               'country' => 'CH',
               'score' => 14.70808550760029,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        2 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2020-03-18T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 13.299189761918104,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 5,
               'country' => 'RU',
               'score' => 13.299189761918104,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        3 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 19.02841337415393,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 77,
               'country' => 'DE',
               'score' => 19.02841337415393,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        4 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2020-10-02T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 2.631257456412845,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 154,
               'country' => 'RU',
               'score' => 2.631257456412845,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        5 => 
        (object) array(
           'timestp' => '2020-10-03T00:00:00.000Z',
           'score' => 1.896575572629275,
           'rank_details' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            (object) array(
               'rank' => 195,
               'country' => 'RU',
               'score' => 1.896575572629275,
               'genre' => 'Country',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),.....
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$apiResponse = curl_exec($cc);
$array = json_decode($apiResponse);
foreach ($array as $key => $arrays) { // This will search in the 2 jsons
    foreach($arrays as $key => $value) {     
        echo "\n Record ID:  " . $value->id;        
        echo "\n Record Name:  " . $value->name;         
        echo "\n Record Rank:  " . $value->obj->data->rank_details->rank;
        echo "\n";    
   }
}
```

Record Name and ID come over fine, but anything not in the "top level" isn't coming over. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Use `json_decode($apiResponse, true);` to work with an associative array

Comment: @jibsteroos Whats that going to achieve, what have you got against Objects

Comment: Can you show us the raw JSON String `$apiResponse` please, then we can decode it and test an answer

Comment: @cmaresh why did you delete your answer, it looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to index into the data and rank_details arrays even if there's only one entry.

This worked for me:

```
echo "\n Record Rank:  " . $value->data[0]->rank_details[0]->rank;
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I had tried the $value->data[0]->rank_details->rank; (forgetting to add the index).